# Password no longer accepted

Tags: user, login, account-password

My admin & secondary access username can't log in.

In phpMyAdmin, both are listed as 0.
What is wrong/how can I recover?

I have found my username in the database, clicked edit, used MD5 and inserted a new password, clicked GO & checked back to my Joomla login. It didn't work, I still have no access.

Comment: It's a very good thing that Joomla doesn't use an outdated encryption technique like `md5()` -- NO currently running applications should be using `md5()` for password encryption purposes.  Anyhow, welcome to JSE Scott and thank you for posting your question.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: the plain md5 hash still works afaik.  but it is unclear what problem you are describing: "both listed as 0" - what is listed as 0? Can any user login? Front or back only? What changed, etc?

Comment: What's the field type of the password field in the #__users table in your database? It should be varchar(100).

Comment: jamesgarrett - The "0" was referring to the "block" column (it's not blocked). Excuse my lack of clarity.

Comment: pe7er - Confirmed, it's varchar(100)

Comment: Sorry guys.
After following many instructions, I realised I hadn't covered one basic!
Tried MS Edge, and login succeeds.
Fault lies with Chrome login. How to correct I still don't know, but I guess this isn't the place to ask.